# Is this $\theta$ measured through vertical axis or from initial position?

Tags: calculus, classical-mechanics

> Two equal particles $A$ and $B$ are attached to the ends of a light rigid rod of length
> $2a$. The rod is supported in the position of unstable equilibrium with $A$ in contact
> with a smooth horizontal table and $B$ above $A$ making an acute angle $\alpha$ with the
> vertical axis. Find the velocity of $A$ when the rod has turned through angle $θ$ and
> thrust on the table.

Is this $\theta$ measured through vertical axis or from initial position? Can anyone help me to understand the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

The gravity center maintains the $x$ coordinate constant along the movement. The initial potential energy is equal to the kinetic energy when the rod thrust on the table. Also there exists a holonomic constraint which is $y = a\sin\theta(t)$